# Laravel Separate Admin Panel |

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a laravel site [www.myExampleDomain.com](http://www.myExampleDomain.com) .I want to add my admin panel in the site.
While customer hit [www.myExampleDomain.com](http://www.myExampleDomain.com) they will see the customer site.when admin hit [www.myExampleDomain.com/admin](http://www.myExampleDomain.com/admin) admin will see the admin panel.

so I want to keep my codes separated for customer panel and admin panel.
like: all the routes of customer will be in customer_web.php and all the routes of  admin will be in admin_web.php.also all the controller for admin in adminController folder and view in AdminView folder separately. How can I handle the separation?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use the `Route` `group()` with `prefixes` method as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-groups):

> Route groups allow you to share route attributes, such as middleware or namespaces, across a large number of routes without needing to define those attributes on each individual route. Shared attributes are specified in an array format as the first parameter to the Route::group method.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/dashboard" URL
    });
});
```